# Computing means by group

Tags: r

With the codes below, I am getting the means of a set of variables (var1, var2, and var3) by a grouping variable (group) and displaying the variables in rows and group categories in coloumns. Are there alternative ways of doing this?

```
var1 <- c(1,4,3,2,4)
var2 <- c(5,2,3,2,1)
var3 <- c(3,3,2,4,5)
group <- c("A","B","A","A","B")
mydata <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,group)
m <- aggregate(cbind(var1, var2, var3)~group, mydata, mean)
m
m <- as.matrix(m)
t(m)
```

Comment: Your way of doing it is pretty effective. Please be more specific what you're looking for.

Comment: This question falls outside the scope of SO since it is *primarily opinion based*

Comment: Your way is very elegant. I like it because it is done with base R.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise_all(mean) %>% 
   gather(key, val, -group) %>% 
   spread(group, val)
```

---

Or using `base R` with `by` and `colMeans`

```
do.call(cbind, by(mydata[1:3], mydata$group, FUN = colMeans))
#.          A   B
#var1 2.000000 4.0
#var2 3.333333 1.5
#var3 3.000000 4.0
```

Or make it compact with `split`

```
sapply(split(mydata[1:3], mydata$group), colMeans)
```

Answer (score 3):

A great case to test the new `patterns` for `.SDcols` in data.table..
need data.table 1.12.0!

Nice, since you can easily select the columns you want to summarise on, using a regex pattern `"^var"` in this example... kind of like the (great) tidy-selectors from the tidyverse, but with the data.table speed-advantages :)

only one line of code needed!!

```
library( data.table )
setDT(mydata)[, lapply( .SD, mean ), by = .( group ), .SDcols = patterns( "^var" )][]

#    group var1     var2 var3
# 1:     A    2 3.333333    3
# 2:     B    4 1.500000    4
```

**benchmarking**

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
data.table = setDT(mydata)[, lapply( .SD, mean), by = .( group ), .SDcols = patterns( "^var" )][],
tidyverse = {mydata %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean) %>% 
  gather(key, val, -group) %>% 
  spread(group, val)
})

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# data.table 1.884407 1.994217 3.095897 2.619641 2.847096 47.288805   100
# tidyverse 5.003995 5.402869 5.650821 5.633938 5.836086  6.643474   100
```

Comment: I just added a `data.table` alternative before seeing this. You might want to reshape though.

Answer (score 2):

@akrun has given a nice `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach. Here's a `reshape2` addition

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
mydata %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean) %>% 
  melt() %>% 
  dcast(variable~group)
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
DT<-mydata[,lapply(.SD,mean),by=.(group),.SDcols=c("var1","var2","var3")]
melted<-melt.data.table(DT,id.vars = "group")
dcast(melted,variable~group)
```

Comment: so basically what @akrun did but the long - wide operation you are doing with `reshape` instead of `tidyr`, but the rest of your code is in `dplyr`...? ... Why?

Comment: I wrote this answer almost at the same time as akrun's comment, so I changed to reshape2 and I had initially not melted. @Sotos

Comment: Its okay.  But, I heard that `reshape2` is getting deprecated.  It may be better to show the `data.table` version of `melt`.

Comment: @akrun I m not surprised. I used to use `reshape2` a lot about 3 years ago when I first started learning R. Now, I forgot it even existed

Comment: @Sotos also some functions are not a replacement i.e. gather and melt have different behavior in certain cases.  I assume that they will have some functions in the tidyr to make up